# Reasons Community rejects edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits, community-user, rejected-edits

I recently [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/960853), and the [Community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) rejected it within a fraction of a second.

What causes this behavior, and what can one do to prevent it from happening?

Is this possibly related to me logging on from the computer next to the one I usually use?

Comment: "Within a fraction of a second" is a huge exaggeration, it was 12 seconds after you suggested it.

Comment: I can assure you it had nothing to do with the computer you were using, though.

Comment: I would guess some form of colliding edits happening.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

12 seconds after you suggested this edit, Madbreaks modified [his prior revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13294045/3). (Edits within a small time window are collapsed into one, which is why only *one* Madbreaks edit appears in the post's [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13294045/revisions).)

Madbreaks' edit came after yours, and therefore clobbered yours. He loaded the edit the page to start editing *before* you suggested the edit though, which is why he didn't have a chance to approve/reject it before editing.

This is a bit of an edge case, but definitely not a very user-friendly experience, so we'll take a look at ways of improving it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Cheers, I've seen it happening more than once and confused users ask about it here. Looking forward to see the progress! :)

Comment: Yes, this has happened to me too and I wasn't sure what was going on.