# Why was suggested edit rejected by Community?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, community-user

The [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1697563) corrected formatting issues in the code posted by the OP. In the [initial post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15355258/1) you can see line breaks in the code posted.

Most of the time when someone rejects a suggested edit, a proper reason is given, like *This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.*. Shouldn't [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) also provide some reason while rejecting suggested edits?

**Update**
Another similar [example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1698036). A reviewer [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1651073/frank) approves and [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) rejects (ofcourse without sharing any reasons) !

Comment: This is pretty common in the first few minutes of a bad post life. Many users jump on the edit wagon and the first wins. If the first was user with more than 2000 rep, it means kicking any suggested edits out. Frustrating yet that's how it works, so just wait 5 minutes before suggesting your edit.

Comment: What about `The Community` (super user) forgetting (by mistake or intentionally) to drop some comment while rejecting the edit ?

Comment: What comment should it make? It's not an actual user.

Comment: The "community" user is just a bot, I agree there should be a comment like "Auto rejected due to other edit" but that should be a separate feature request.

Comment: What about another example http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1698036 ? No other submitted the edit before mine. The revisions (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15356364/revisions) say it was edited by the OP way after my suggested edit was rejected.

Comment: @Apurv in this case the OP clicked "edit" before you clicked it and submitted it after you submitted your suggestion, having same effect as before since OP "vote" is binding as well. It's not showing in revisions history as it was within the five minutes grace period.

Comment: Some research I did into this suggests that waiting out the 5-minute grace period is just better for everyone: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164802/is-suggesting-an-edit-soon-after-initial-posting-a-discouraged-behavior

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looking at revision history and the timestamps of both examples you provided, one possibility for the reason your edits were rejected was not because you lost an edit race with a 2K user, but you actually lost an edit race with the OP of the questions AND it was within the 5 minute grace period of the edit.  The likely order of what happen is something like:

- OP posts his/her question
- You click edit on the question shortly after it was posted
- Shortly after you (or possibly before you), the OP clicks "edit"
- You commit your edit
- Shortly afterward, the OP commits his/her edit.  Since it is within the 5 minute grace period, no edit history is captured.  It still appears as if the original posting is the most recent revision

This scenerio would also explain the time lapse between your suggested edits, the rejection time, and when the next edit was captured in the revision history

Because the OP has a binding vote on edits for his/her question, your edit is rejected by Community (this is a similar effect as if a 2K user reviewed your edit and tried to improve your edit from within the review queue - when this happens your edit is immediately rejected or accepted by Community).  But since it was within the 5 minute grace period after the post was made, there was no indication in the suggest edit as to who edited your question after you.

But in general, Community never provides a reason for the reject.  Because it does not have the ability to think for itself (yet), it does not know why it is rejecting the edit.

Answer (score 4):

It was probably rejected because it was edited by another user at the same time.

Comment: Another similar example -> http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1698036

Comment: Indeed, it appears that Jesper edited the post outside the review system (probably clicking "edit" before the edit was suggested) hence the edit conflicted with the suggested edit and kicked it out.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Who Jesper ? Do you mean OP ?

Comment: @Apurv no I mean [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/135589/jesper) who edited the post, see the [revisions page](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15355258/revisions). He didn't reject your suggestion, he just clicked "edit" before you clicked "edit" and he sent his own edit after you sent your suggestion causing the suggestion to get auto rejected.

Comment: What about another example http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1698036 ? No other submitted the edit before mine. The revisions (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15356364/revisions) say it was edited by the OP way after my suggested edit was rejected.