# Community Rejecting Suggested Edits (aka Community gone astray)

Tags: discussion, edits, review, suggested-edits, community-user

Community rejected the following edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2455044

I  resubmitted a similar edit, which was approved (I think Community was on a coffee break):

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2455226

This is the revision history of the question.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17504147/revisions

Now I had noticed that the OP deleted the question for a short time.

Is the reason Community rejected the edit because of the deletion or is there another reason?

What does one do, when Community has rejected a valuable edit?

Why was the suggested edit approved the second time around?

Comment: Could it be http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171426?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "Why did the edit get through a second time?" - Why wouldn't it go through a second time? You submitted the edit again...

Comment: @brasofilo no this doesn't answer it, as the edits are shown

Comment: @animuson it was rejected the first time, automatically (by community), so I was not sure it would be approved the second time I made the edit suggestion

Comment: @animuson I reworded my question, pls advise if it has clarity

Comment: I was thinking that the delete caused it. But the timestamps don't really support that theory. The edit was actually rejected at 15:06:24, which is 20 seconds before the post was deleted at 15:06:43. So the link provided by brasofilo seems more probable.

Comment: @Yve: brasofilo's link does seem to answer it. Why don't you think it does?

Comment: No it doesn't Mat, please see Animuson's comment, and also, the edits I made, that Community rejected are there, in this other question the edits are not saved, for other reasons.. and yes, I am not convinced it was the deletion either. I had noticed a few times that the edits were being faulty, with flags like "no changes have been made" and "this should be a suggested edit" I think there is a bug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can see and guess from the timestamps. You've suggested an edit, and then one of the following happened:

- Either the OP was exactly editing the post, and it was within the grace period.
- Or the OP wanted to edit your suggested edit later, and he chose to "improve" without marking the "suggested edit was useful".

I think it's more likely to be the first.